# How to change http to https using LetsEncrypt with 'docker: nginx + uwgsi + django + solr + db + ...'?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, https, uwsgi

Currently I use official `nginx` docker image + my own 'django with uwsgi' build and everything works ok. I want to add `SSL` to the project using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` + `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`.

The structure of my project is the next:

```
myproject/
| -- data/
| -- media/
| -- static/
| -- sources/
     | -- dockerfiles/
          | -- nginx/
               | -- nginx.conf
               | -- uwsgi_params
          | -- solr/
               | -- default/ (configs)
               | -- Dockerfile
          | -- web/
               | -- Dockerfile
               | -- requirements.txt
     | -- myproject/
          | -- app_1/
          | -- app_2/
          | -- settings/
               | -- myproject_uwsgi.ini
     | -- docker-compose.yml
```

The relative configs are below:

```
# myproject/sources/docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: myproject_nginx-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media

  web:
    build: ./dockerfiles/web/
    container_name: myproject_django-container
    command: bash -c 'uwsgi --ini ./settings/myproject_uwsgi.ini'
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media

  solr-docker:
    build: ./dockerfiles/solr/
    container_name: myproject_solr-container
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - default
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/solr/default:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default  # configs
      - ../data/solr/default/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default/data  # indexes

  # other-services...
```

next:

```
# myproject/sources/myproject/settings/myproject_uwsgi.ini

[uwsgi]

master = True
lazy-apps = True

# Number of worker processes for handling requests
%k = cpu count
processes = %(%k * 2)

# Number of threads for handling requests
threads = %(%k * 2)

# Respawn processes that take more than ... seconds
# harakiri = 20

# Respawn processes after serving ... requests
max-requests = 5000

# Clear environment on exit
vacuum = True

# the base directory (full path)
chdir = /myproject/

# Django's wsgi file (path starting from chdir/)
module = settings.wsgi:application

# location of settings
# env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$(DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME).settings

socket = :8000
```

and one more:

```
# myproject/dockerfiles/nginx/nginx.conf

upstream django {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# Redirection from WWW to non-WWW
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myproject.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://myproject.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name myproject.com;
    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /media  {
        alias /media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

`uwsgi_params` file has a typical configuration which can be seen [HERE](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params).

How to convert `http` to `https` you can find in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement `https`, it is necessary to add to the existing `docker-compose.yml` the next two images: `jwilder/nginx-proxy` + `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` and add environment variables for: `nginx` service which serves `django` via `uwsgi` + for `solr`. Everything else (configs) can be kept as is.

So here is the final result:

```
# myproject/sources/docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy: # <-- NEW SECTION
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: myproject_nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
      - "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"

  letsencrypt-companion: # <-- NEW SECTION
    restart: always
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: myproject_letsencrypt-companion-container
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw"

  # ###############################
  # Old settings. ALMOST identical.
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: myproject_nginx-container

    # ports:  <-- REMOVE SECTION
    #   - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy # <-- NEW SECTION
      - web
    environment: # <-- NEW SECTION
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myproject.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myproject.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@myproject.com

  web:
    build: ./dockerfiles/web/
    container_name: myproject_django-container
    command: bash -c 'uwsgi --ini ./settings/myproject_uwsgi.ini'
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media

  solr-docker:
    build: ./dockerfiles/solr/
    container_name: myproject_solr-container
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - default
    # ports:  <-- REMOVE SECTION
    #   - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/solr/default:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default  # configs
      - ../data/solr/default/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default/data  # indexes
    environment: # <-- NEW SECTION
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=solr.myproject.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8983
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=solr.myproject.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@myproject.com

  # other-services...
```

If you want to open `Solr`'s dashboard now, instead of `myproject.com:8983` you need to use `solr.myproject.com`.